# Compare input parameter of c++ macro

Tags: c++, macros

I have a macro like that:

```
#define M(x)
```

I want check x, if it is equal to `void` or not. Something like that:

```
#define M(x)
    if(x == void)
        do not return anything
    else
        print a output
```

Problem is that `x` may be anything. M may be called with any parameters.
    M(int)
    M(string)
    M(void)

I want this macro can be detect input parameter is `void`.

**Update 1:** better explain

This is a function creator macro. Like that (simple code)

```
#define M(ret, name) \
    ret name(){ \
        ret r = callOtherFunc(); \
        return r; \
    }
```

And I want if ret is void then the line 'return...' removed

**Update 2:** Forget template

Please do not suggest using templates. This is a part of bigger solution. This small part of solution can be solved with templates, but the bigger solution must be solved with macros. So please post your answers of **only** related to macro and not template.

Comment: You cannot. The C++ preprocessor is not designed to do this.

Comment: Use templates for this

Comment: "Forget template" - you need to explain why you can't use templates *for this little bit*.  There's nothing wrong with mixing templates and macros (it's often the best way).

Comment: You also need to explain why `ret name() { return callOtherFunc(); }` doesn't work for you.

Comment: I have a project named noron:
https://github.com/HamedMasafi/Noron

In this project I have a tool named peer-generator, this tool generate a class. I want avoid this tool and replace it with macros.

Developer define methods in interface class by using macros. and thid macros should automatically generate 5 method per each. 

The methods should define in interface class and was callable (as normal method) so templates is not good idea. I wrote 420 line macro for detecting and parsing method parameters and etc. but problem is that these methods have return statement for non-void types.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define M(x) std::is_same<x,void>::value
```

<sub>The check with `void` happens *after* preprocessing stage. Though above is correct way, I may not do in real code. However, you haven't given the full context of what you exactly want. Hence, I am putting this as an answer.</sub>

**Update 1**: It appears that you want to create a functions using macros. And those give error only for the `void` types because an object cannot return an object of `void`. Here is how you should do it:

```
#define M(ret, name) \
    ret name(){ \
        return callOtherFunc(); \  // not storing in temporary
    }
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/I5g1In).

But I still sense that, you may want something more. Hence, try to put a good verifiable example containing all you want.

Comment: Problem is not temporary storage of variable. Problem is:
> And those give error only for the void types because an object cannot return an object of void

Comment: @BlackDal, you cannot use same macro for `void` & other types, in case if you intend to store the variable in temporary. Probably you can describe your exact problem in the question with bigger picture, so that people can help.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative option is to use templates:

```
template <typename T> void M(){
    if(std::is_same<T,void>::value){
        std::cout << "void!\n";
    }
    else{
        std::cout <<"Not void!\n";
    }
}

int main(){
    M<void>();
    M<int>();
}
```

Result:

> void!
>
> Not void!

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/3xcws)

Answer (score -1):

Yo can't do this. The **Macro** are not type safe. That is a macro define for `int` operation cannot accept other data like `float`. They are explained with no type checking.

So, you can use **template** function.